# Does Elixir Garbage Collector suffer from stop the world pause?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Compared to Java where lot of objects will force "stop the world garbage collector to run" and "pause" the execution, how will Elixir gc behave?

To elaborate on this If I have created 1 million processes which are short lived and are supposed to finish within certain SLA then will Elixir provide better reliability compared to Java?

Comment: Yes, Elixir will provide better reliability, ErlangVM does not stop the world and there are tons of articles in the internet on this exact subject.

Comment: Java objects "will for"?  What does that mean?

Comment: Not a subject for this forum. You will find some explanation there: [link](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/erlang-garbage-collector.html)

Comment: I recommend to read https://hamidreza-s.github.io/erlang%20garbage%20collection%20memory%20layout%20soft%20realtime/2015/08/24/erlang-garbage-collection-details-and-why-it-matters.html

Comment: @7stud I modified the question..thank you for pointing out

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank your answering straight. Could you please direct me to some relevant links?